# GIT Commit to FTP Site

Tags: ftp, git

I am working on a project where I only have FTP control of the server. I am basically hand deploying changes from GIT commits to the server.

Is there any way to automate this (without writing the script myself, which I'm about to do), without being able to install git on the server?

Comment: You could also push into a local bare repo, and then sync it up on the fs level with any ftpsync tool. It is not an okay solution if the repo on the ftp is used by multiple people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need is [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp). I never tried it, anyway.

Comment: Thanks, David, that looks quite awesome. I'll check it out.

Comment: return if it fixed your problem

Answer (score 3):

While I was waiting for answers, I cooked this up. Though now I"ll have to check out git-ftp as David Costa suggests. This script doesn't actually do anything: it just gives you commands for your own FTPing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
if __FILE__ == $0
  puts "Pulls file list between two git commits and makes ftp commands"
  if ARGV.length != 2
    puts "Sorry, include two hashes as arguments separated by spaces"
    exit
  end

  hash1 = ARGV[0]
  hash2 = ARGV[1]

  command = "git log #{hash1}..#{hash2} --name-status --pretty=\"%p\""

  results = `#{command}`
  results = results.to_a[2..-1].join

  lines = results.to_a
  lines.each do |line|
    modifyAddDelete = line[0..0]
    if (modifyAddDelete=="M" || modifyAddDelete=="A")
      command = "put"
    elsif (modifyAddDelete = "D")
      command = "delete"
    end
    filename = line[2..1000]
    puts "#{command} #{filename}"

  end

end
```